# $$ \left(\frac{\text{Man}^{\text{fr}}}{\text{Cobordism}},\coprod,\times \right)\simeq \left((\text{Fin}^{\simeq},\coprod)^{\text{gp}},\times\right)?$$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, smooth-manifolds

If we combine a theorem of Pontryagin and the Barratt-Priddy-Quillen theorem we get that both sides of

$$
\left(\frac{\mathrm{Man}^{\mathrm{fr}}}{\mathrm{Cobordism}},\coprod,\times \right)\simeq \left((\mathrm{Fin}^{\simeq},\coprod)^{\mathrm{gp}},\times\right)
$$

is equivalent to $\pi_*(S)$, hence both sides are equivalent, right?

Does this equivalence respect the arithmetic of both sides?

Edit: I think there should be $\pi_*(\text{right hand side})$ for the equivalence to hold.

Comment: The Pontriagin theorem is about the relationship between framed cobordism and homotopy groups of spheres.  The Barratt-Priddy theorem is about the relationship between group homology of the symmetric group and homology of mapping spaces of spheres.  So I'm not sure how you are putting the two together.  Could you be more specific?

Comment: It think that there is mistake in the question: I think it is the homotopy groups of the righthand side that is in the equivalence.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see comment above. I think you are right.

Comment: This was very useful and fun for me to think about. Sorry for imprecision and mistakes.

Comment: The closest thing I know to the theme of your question would be Fred Cohen's work relating sub-quotients of braid groups (Brunnian braid groups) to homotopy groups of spheres.

Comment: Thank you! I think I was mixing up the infinite loop space of the sphere spectrum (right hand side) and the ring of homotopy groups of the sphere spectrum (left hand side).

Comment: Thank you @RyanBudney for suggestion. I think this is what I need.